# Loop that is removing duplicate posts isn't posting the right amount of posts

Tags: wordpress, loops

I have two loops, the first is posting the four most recent posts while excluding one category. The second is supposed to post all of the most recent posts except the ones that are in the first loop.

What ends up happening is that the first loop posts the four most recent posts (which is what I'm looking for, so yay!), but the second loop will run through the loop twice, and if a posts is in the first loop, it will post one less post than it should.

For example, when the second loop runs, it finds a post from category 10, and it displays it as it should, then it finds a post from category 2, which is in the first loop, it doesn't post that poss, but then it stops before finding two postable posts.

```
<div id="new-article-wrapper">
<?php
  $new_articles = new WP_Query('cat=-10&posts_per_page=4');
  //Array to save post IDs
  $ids = array();

  if ($new_articles->have_posts()) :
  while ($new_articles->have_posts()) : $new_articles->the_post();

    get_template_part('partials/loop', 'new_articles_1');

  //Save post IDs into array
  $ids[]= $post->ID;
  endwhile;
  else :
  endif;
  wp_reset_postdata();?>

<?php
  $new_articles_all = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=2');

  if ($new_articles_all->have_posts()) :
  while ($new_articles_all->have_posts()) : $new_articles_all->the_post();

  //Check for duplicates
  if (!in_array($post->ID, $ids)) {
    get_template_part('partials/loop', 'new_articles_2');
  }
  endwhile;
  else :
  endif;
  wp_reset_postdata();?>

</div><!-- id="new_articles" -->
```

What I'd want the second loop to do is to go through the loop again when it finds a duplicate post, but without incriminating so no matter how many duplicate posts are found, the loop always outputs two posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only asking for 2 posts

```
$new_articles_all = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=2');
```

If one of those posts is in your ID list then only one is left to be displayed. To be sure you need to ask for at least size of new_articles + 2 .

And if you want to make sure the second loop only displays 2 posts, then have a counter variable and break out of the while loop when it gets to 2.

Comment: Added an: 

    $i=0;

then a:

    if ($i==2) {
      break;
    }

before the if this then grab template statement and that seems to have solved the issue :)